# Problemas al sumar valores de tabla dinámica con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Al momento de realizar la suma cuando se suman las filas me genera bien el resultado.

Al momento de sumar las columnas simplemente no genera ningún resultado.

No se si se pueda duplicar los valores en la función y por esta razón es que no esta dando las sumas de los valores en las columnas o que también se están duplicando las variables donde generara el resultado.

Intente cambiándole los indicadores del *for* pero de igual forma no genera ningún resultado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_ES">
<head>
<script>
function calculo(trId,tdId) {
var trInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#tr-${trId} input`);
var trTotal = 0;

trInputs.forEach(function(input) {
trTotal += parseInt(input.value) || 0;
});

document.querySelector(`#tr-${trId} #spTotal`).innerHTML = trTotal;

var tdInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#td-${tdId} input`);
var tdTotal = 0;

tdInputs.forEach(function(input) {
tdTotal += parseInt(input.value) || 0;
});

document.querySelector(`#td-${tdId} #spTotaltd`).innerHTML = tdTotal;
}
function crear(){
var col = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var filas = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var tabla="<table border=\"1\" id=\"miTabla\">";
tabla+="<tr><td>Matriz</td>";
for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
tabla+="<td>"+(j+1)+"</td>";
}
tabla+="<td>Total</td>";
tabla+="</tr>";

for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
tabla+="<tr id='tr-" + i + "'>";
tabla+="<td>"+(i+1)+ "</td>";
for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
    // Enviar evento en lugar del campo y sin asignar ID
tabla+="<td id='td-" + i + "'>"+'<input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" 
onchange=\"calculo(' +i+ ');\"/>'+ "</td>";
}
// Asignar clase a la celda que va a contener la suma
tabla+="<td id=\"spTotal\"></td>";
tabla+="</tr>";
}
tabla+="<tr id='tr-" + i + "'>";
tabla+="<td>Total</td>";
for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
tabla+="<td id=\"spTotal\"></td>";
}
tabla+="<td id=\"spTotaltotal\"></td>";
tabla+="</tr>";
tabla+="</table>";
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=tabla;
}

function crear2() {
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML="";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="cols" /> Inserte el numero de Matriz <br />
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="crear tabla" onclick="crear()"/>
<input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar" onclick="crear2()"/>

</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En el fragmento de código no se ve dónde estás realizando el cálculo por columna.

Comment: function calculo(trId,tdId) {
  var trInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#tr-${trId} input`);
  var trTotal = 0;

  trInputs.forEach(function(input) {
    trTotal += parseInt(input.value) || 0;
  });

  document.querySelector(`#tr-${trId} #spTotal`).innerHTML = trTotal;

  var tdInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#td-${tdId} input`);
  var tdTotal = 0;

  tdInputs.forEach(function(input) {
    tdTotal += parseInt(input.value) || 0;
  });

  document.querySelector(`#td-${tdId} #spTotaltd`).innerHTML = tdTotal;
}

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para actualizar el código, no se puede analizar bien como comentario.